# VBA macro or functon to copy cell values based on criteria to a master sheet

Tags: vba, excel, function

Let’s say I have a rental car company and I have 12 sheets with 10 columns each and unknown amount of rows. Each sheet is holding information about cars rented. Below are the column headings for each spreadsheet

```
 - A.   Date rented 
 - B.   Customer Name
 - C.   Customer Address
 - D.   Customer Phone
 - E.   Customer email 
 - F.   Car Year
 - G.   Car Make
 - H.   Car Model
 - I.   Car Plate number
 - J.   Car Vin
```

I have a master sheet that I want to get specific information from all sheets and copy the cellValues of those sheets into the master sheet. I’m not familiar with VBA so Here is the sudocode of the loop I want to do:

```
For each sheet
 For each row
  Copy customer name, customer phone, car plate number into next available row on master sheet
```

In the master sheet, the columns would be respectively how I put them in the sudocode

```
 - A.   Customer Name
 - B.   Customer Phone
 - C.   Car Plate number
```

Can someone show me what the VBA macro code would be for this?

Disclaimer: this is not my actual information in my spreadsheet as what I am working on is confidential so I can’t provide screenshots. This is just example information that simulates what I want to do.

I've tried =HLOOKUP(B1,'Sheet1 (51)'!1:1048576,2:2,FALSE) but getting a value error or an NA error, depending on what range or values I try in the parameters.  The way I was understanding the HLookup function is this:

1. lookup value is the column heading I'm looking for within the source sheet: for customer name I would but B2 for the lookup value
2. The table array would be the whole source sheet
3. The row array would be the row I'm getting the cell value from in the source sheet
4. range lookup is either T or F or nothing as it is optional.  If i use True or False, I get the NA error if I use nothing I get the value error.

The idea is that once I get this formula working for one cell then expand it to one row then expand it to the loop i have in my sudocode for all rows within the source sheet, then expand it to look or go to the next source sheet.

Comment: "Can someone show me what the VBA macro code would be for this?" - SO is not a "code for me" site/service.  For that, you can hire a freelancer/programmer.  SO is a "help me with my code" site.  Please make some attempts at what you're trying to do, and when you get stuck, post what you've tried, what's getting an error/not working, etc. and we'd be happy to help!  You could even maybe do this with formulas. At the very least, there are myriad examples on SO, and the web in general, of looping through sheets and rows, looking for data, and pasting it elsewhere.  Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: I've tried =HLOOKUP(A1,'Sheet1 (51)'!1:1048576,2:2,FALSE) but getting a value error

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this fairly easily by looping through all the available sheets, excluding the master sheet and setting the relevant range for each sheet. Then using the find function to get the last row of data in the master sheet to be able to append the next rows.

This should produce the desired result:

```
Sub MasterGrab()

Dim master As Worksheet
Dim subSheet As Range
Dim i As Integer
Dim lastRow As Long

Set master = Worksheets("MasterSheet")
x = Sheets.Count
lastRow = master.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row 'find last row on master sheet
lastRow = lastRow + 1

For i = 1 To x
    If Not Sheets(i).Name = "MasterSheet" Then 'capture all sheets except MasterSheet
        Set subSheet = Sheets(i).Range("A1:J" & ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row) 'set each sheet range to cover required data
        For Each r In subSheet.Rows
            master.Cells(lastRow, 1) = r.Cells(2) 'Customer name
            master.Cells(lastRow, 2) = r.Cells(4) 'Customer phone
            master.Cells(lastRow, 3) = r.Cells(9) 'Car Plate number
            lastRow = lastRow + 1
        Next r

    End If
Next i
End Sub
```